# How to use rewrite rules using .htaccess in an aliased directory outside document root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

I am trying to use `.htaccess` to rewrite requests for PHP files that don't explicitly include the `.php` file extension (e.g. `example.com/foo` should rewrite to `example.com/foo.php`), but *without* applying that rule to any folders (or subfolders) of the document root.

My `http.conf` file contains following:

```
DocumentRoot "/webfiles"
<Directory "/webfiles">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias "/exams" "/training/exams"
<Directory "/training/exams">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

There is a `.htaccess` file in the `/training/exams` folder containing following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The goal is to:

1. serve requests like `example.com/exams` with `/training/exams/index.php` file,
2. serve requests like `example.com/exams/first` with `/training/exams/first.php` file,
3. while still having requests like `example.com/myhome.html` served with `/webfiles/myhome.html`.

Examples 1. and 3. work fine, but for 2. I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

This ultimately ends up trying to rewrite the URL to `/training/exams/first.php` (after the directory-prefix is added back). I think that mod_rewrite (in a *directory* context) is seeing this as a URL-path and `example.com/training/exams/first.php` doesn't exist, hence the 404.

You can either use the `RewriteBase` directive to override the directory-prefix with the correct root-relative URL-path instead. For example:

```
RewriteBase /exams
```

Or, hardcode the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /exams/$1.php [L]
```

(No need for the `NC` flag or to escape the literal dot when used in a character class.)

Or, use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable to construct a root-relative URL-path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite for your advise. I have tried `RewriteBase` as well as hardcode the URL-path without any success, same result. However, when I used `REQUEST_URI` in the rewrite rule in `.htaccess` within the `/exams` sub-folder, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Curious, I would have expected all 3 _variations_ to have worked?! Since they are really just variations of the same thing. I would expect the `REQUEST_URI` server variable to contain `/exams/first` in your example (since that is presumably the URL being requested?).

Comment: If you have time, I would be interested to see what the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains. eg. Change the last rule to read: `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php?mru=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` and check the value of `$_GET['mru']` in your `first.php` script when requesting `/exams/first`. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Here is the result: `value of $_GET['mru'] is: /exams/first` of the code: `echo 'value of <b>$_GET[\'mru\']</b> is: ' . $_GET['mru'];`

Comment: Ok, that's as expected. So, what did the previous rule return? This time change the last rule to read: `RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}.php?urlpath=$1 [L]` and check the value of `$_GET['urlpath']` in your `first.php` script when requesting `/exams/first` (as before). Thanks.

Comment: OK. Result: `value of $_GET['urlpath'] is: first`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Again, that is the expected value so really all 3 variations above _should_ have worked? Anyway, glad it's working.